# Using X-sendfile with utf-8 files without updating my files or database

Tags: django, utf-8, apache2, ascii, x-sendfile

On my site we have thousands of documents that we want to serve using x-sendfile. Unfortunately, many of them have funky utf-8 characters in their titles, and, what with HTTP not supporting utf-8, x-sendfile doesn't exactly either.

I can make x-sendfile work properly by changing the names of my files to be URL encoded, and by updating my database to mirror those values, but that sucks since I have so many files, and it feels dumb to have them all named with various URL encodings when my OS (and most everything else) supports utf-8.

**Is there a way I can use x-sendfile without changing my file names and database?**

Comment: "HTTP not supporting utf-8" [citation needed]

Comment: Hrm, looks like you may be right about that, but django does struggle with this, as does x-sendfile: http://ben.timby.com/?p=149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the latest version of xsendfile (not the one currently on the website, but rather the one from github), this works automatically!